# Funky Sql Generated using SubSonic Simple Repository, LINQ and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, subsonic3, subsonic-simplerepository

I have the following code:

```
if (collection["Filter"] == "2") { 
   presentations = presentations.Where(x => x.Speaker.FirstName.StartsWith("B")).
   OrderBy(x => x.Speaker.FirstName);
}
```

this generates the following sql:

```
SELECT  [t0].[Description], [t0].[EventId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[PresentedOn], 
        [t0].[Slug], [t0].[SpeakerId], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Url]
FROM    [Presentations] AS t0
LEFT    OUTER JOIN [Speakers] AS t1 ON ([t1].[Id] = [t0].[Id])
WHERE   ([t1].[FirstName] LIKE 'B' + '%')
ORDER   BY [t1].[FirstName]
```

The problem is the join should be:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Speakers] AS t1 ON ([t1].[Id] = [t0].[SpeakerId])
```

Any ideas how to correct this problem? Linked to [ASP.NET MVC2 Linq Where Clause using StartsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262155/asp-net-mvc2-linq-where-clause-using-startswith)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think the SubSonic Linq provider is very 'mature'.

Comment: I appreciate you comment, but it's not very helpful. This is not the first problem with subsonic and I will agree with you though.

Comment: Not an answer.  Did you intend for this to be a comment on the OP instead?