# SubSonic3 SimpleRepository Relationships Generated are Wrong

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-2, subsonic3, subsonic-simplerepository

I have been told that it's more than likely my database that is setup wrong causing the problems so below are my tables with key fields and queries.

```
CREATE TABLE Presentations (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),
    SpeakerId INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_Presentations PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Presentations_Speaker FOREIGN KEY (SpeakerId) REFERENCES Speakers (Id)
)

CREATE TABLE Speakers (
    Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1),

    CONSTRAINT PK_Speakers PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

When I execute the following:

```
presentations = presentations.OrderBy(x => x.Speaker.FirstName);
```

The query generated looks like:

```
SELECT  [t0].[Description], [t0].[EventId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[PresentedOn], 
        [t0].[Slug], [t0].[SpeakerId], [t0].[Title], [t0].[Url]
FROM    [Presentations] AS t0
LEFT    OUTER JOIN [Speakers] AS t1 ON ([t1].[Id] = [t0].[Id])
WHERE   ([t1].[FirstName] LIKE 'B' + '%')
ORDER   BY [t1].[FirstName]
```

The join should be:

```
LEFT    OUTER JOIN [Speakers] AS t1 ON ([t1].[Id] = [t0].[SpeakerId])
```

This is an urgent problem, can anyone help?

Related Questions:

- [ASP.NET MVC2 Linq Where Clause using StartsWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262155/asp-net-mvc2-linq-where-clause-using-startswith)
- [Funky Sql Generated using SubSonic Simple Repository, LINQ and ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264435/funky-sql-generated-using-subsonic-simple-repository-linq-and-asp-net-mvc)

Really appreciate some help.

Comment: We might be making some assumptions about the key names in the tables, but I don't think so.  What version are you using and does the generated table information have the correct name for the key?

Comment: Tables aren't generated, I coded them as I wasn't always using SubSonic3

Comment: Did you resolve this I'm intrigued

Comment: Ended up with some really hackish code that ruined my pattern. Looking into other options.